# android notification bar show/hide toggle

Tags: android, hide, show, android-notification-bar

I am making an app where I would like the notification bar to be toggled for being show/ not being shown. Is that possible? I already know how to set button listener/override buttons but I just need the java code that makes that possible. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Get a full-screen window
final Window win = getWindow();
win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Be aware that:

> Note that some flags must be set before the window decoration is created (by the first call to setContentView(View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) or getDecorView()

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags(int,%20int)

Comment: I know that, but is it possible to get the notification bar back through code by a similar function?

Comment: I'm looking into this myself, I noticed what I want is currently a feature in the default clock app on froyo roms, so I'll try to find that source code on the google page